# Access private sounds in my iPhone app from soundcloud without authenticate

Tags: objective-c, soundcloud

I want to display my sound track from my sound cloud account to all user of my iPhone application ?

I seen that ios sdk of soundclound support authenticate module but if i use that the i am able to get only sounds for that user only.

I have one sound cloud account and I want to display all tracks from that account to all users of my iphone application , How can i do that using sound cloud ios sdk ?

Answer (score 0):

i am not an ios dev, but i hope i can help you a bit.

the api-url / endpoint you will need is:

```
https://api.soundcloud.com/users/{ID}/tracks
```

example:

https://api.soundcloud.com/users/1672444/tracks.json?client_id=679877a8ddb9badc6a2a75373c5f3de7

here is the offical documentation for their ios stuff:

https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/ios-quickstart#using

to retrieve the list, change the url / var from (- or add a new one)

```
NSString *resourceURL = @"https://api.soundcloud.com/me/tracks.json";
```

to

```
NSString *resourceURL = @"https://api.soundcloud.com/users/1672444/tracks.json";
```

You can use this small script to get your SoundClouds user-id, just change the url to yours:

http://jsfiddle.net/iambnz/03zbzL96/

One thing left: Its still an authed call, dont know how to change that correctly. 
I guess withAccount: account is the relevant field / parameter.